# Generate dynamic number of columns from CTE

Tags: sql-server-2016, dynamic-sql, cte, computed-column

A hospital database (SQL Server 2016) has a table of visits to the hospital. If patients transfer to a different specialty, a new visit is made (but from a research perspective it's considered one admission overall).

I've got the below CTE to join connected visits (gaps and islands problem) to form admissions (based on the admit/discharge time of the visit).

```
WITH cte1 AS (
   SELECT
      v.*,
      PrevEnd = LAG(v.DischargeDate) OVER (PARTITION BY v.PatientID ORDER BY v.AdmitDate)
   FROM Visits v
),
cte2 AS (
   SELECT 
      *,
      GroupId = COUNT(CASE WHEN cte1.PrevEnd >= DATEADD(hour, -6, cte1.AdmitDate) THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)
            OVER (PARTITION BY cte1.PatientID ORDER BY cte1.AdmitDate ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
    FROM cte1
),
Numbered AS (
   SELECT 
      *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cte2.PatientID, cte2.GroupID ORDER BY cte2.AdmitDate)
   FROM cte2
)
```

The issue is I would like to create a dataset from this CTE, where there's a dynamic number of `VisitID[n]` columns based on the `MAX(rn) FROM Numbered`, instead of specifying each `VisitID[n]` column manually as I've done below:

```
SELECT
   n.PatientID, 
   AdmitDate = MIN(n.AdmitDate),
   DischargeDate = MIN(n.DischargeDate),
   VisitID  = MIN(CASE WHEN n.rn = 1 THEN n.VisitID END),
   VisitID2 = MIN(CASE WHEN n.rn = 2 THEN n.VisitID END),
   VisitID3 = MIN(CASE WHEN n.rn = 3 THEN n.VisitID END),
   VisitID4 = MIN(CASE WHEN n.rn = 4 THEN n.VisitID END)
FROM Numbered n
GROUP BY
   n.PatientID,
   n.GroupID
ORDER BY
   n.PatientID,
   n.GroupID
;
```

[image: example output]

The actual `Numbered` CTE result may have at least 20 connected visits.

I attempted to create a dynamic SQL string I could use `exec` on, by putting the CTE into a Temp table, but I was met with `Error converting data type varchar to bigint`.

```
DECLARE @maxVisitIDCount INT;
DECLARE @columnNames NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT * INTO #tempVisitGrouped FROM Numbered

SELECT @maxVisitIDCount = MAX(rn) FROM #tempVisitGrouped;
SELECT @columnNames = @columnNames + '[VisitID' + a.rn + '],' FROM (SELECT TOP (@maxVisitIDCount - 1) * FROM #tempVisitGrouped) AS a;
```

I thought I'd ask dba incase there's an easier way to do what I want. How can I generate the number of `VisitID` columns dynamically?

Comment: You need to convert your row number to a string so you can concatenate it to a string rather than attempt maths on it.

Comment: This is where `CONCAT()` could be helpful because it'll automatically handle different data types (and `NULL` when applicable) of the columns you're appending together. Or you can manually cast them (in your case looks like just the `rn` column) yourself like Eric mentioned. Though you really shouldn't do either here because recursive string concatenation is buggy and error prone, Microsoft recommends using `STRING_AGG()` instead, which unfortunately isn't available natively in SQL Server 2016. There's an alternative way using `STUFF()` / `FOR XML PATH` but it's not fun, IMO.

Comment: Why not just add 20 fixed `VisitID` columns, and extra ones will remain `NULL`?

Comment: Relevant post on [so] from OP https://stackoverflow.com/q/73383204/14868997